# ¿Cómo puedo crear una sesion en laravel y validarla en blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

actualmente estoy aprendiendo laravel y me encuentro en la necesidad de crear una variable de session y no entiendo muy bien en algunas respuestas que he encontrado.

mi necesidad es que en un proceso debo crear una session:

en php nativo seria algo así:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['val'] = "String";
?>
```

luego de crear la session necesito validarla en blade

en php nativo seria algo así:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['val'])){
    //TODO
}
?>
```

en resumen debo llevar lo que esta en php pure a laravel, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear una variable en la sesión de Laravel, basta con utilizar el helper `session()`, usando como parámetro de entrada un arreglo de llave > valor:

```
session(['val' => 'string']);
```

Para verificar si existe una variable en la sesión, utilizas el método has() en el Facade de Session:

```
if (Session::has('val')) {
    ...
```

No olvides importar el Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Por favor revisa la documentación de Laravel, todo está explicado muy claro: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que uses mejor el Auth().
Puedes obtener asi variables del usuario registrado de esta forma:

```
Auth::user()->'nombreDelCampo'
```

'user' es el modelo que usas para hacer el login, podria variar si lo haces con otra tabla/modelo pero por defecto es user

```
Auth::user()->id
```

No se si es exactamente lo que buscas pero te lo pongo por si acaso.